# What happens to retained blocks when the retainer is deallocated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Let SomeObject have a member variable _someBlock. SomeObject starts an operation which will cause _someBlock to be executed later. Sometime before the block execution, SomeObject is deallocated.

What happens to _someBlock? Will it be executed or will there be a cascading deallocation causing it to never be executed?

Comment: It depends on if and how you've scheduled the execution. Please add more details. Also, this should be something that's easy enough to try out; what happened when you did so?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "starts an operation which will cause _someBlock to be executed later."  In general, blocks that are queued on dispatch queues or operation queues will be copied with `Block_copy()` and will execute even if the original reference goes away.